# Angular - ng-Template Animation on open/close status

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'd like to create animation when the status of my `ng-template` change but I find nothing about this component...

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/

This is my `report.component.html`

```
<ngb-accordion (click)="arrowRotation(i)" (panelChange)="isOpen($event) "
                   *ngFor="let signature of report.xmlReport.signatures; let i=index">
      <ngb-panel>
        <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p class="v-align">signature {{i + 1}} / {{size}}
              <i *ngIf="signature.errors.length == 0" class="icon-status-ok fa fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i *ngIf="signature.errors.length != 0" class="icon-status-ko fa fa-times"></i>
            </p>
            <fa-icon [id]="arrowID + i" icon="arrow-right"></fa-icon>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
          <app-signature [signature]="signature">
          </app-signature>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-panel>
    </ngb-accordion>
```

This is `my report.component.ts`

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  arrowID: string;
  isShow = true;
  openById = {};

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrowID = 'arrow_' + this.reportType + '_';
  }

  arrowRotation(id) {
    const icon = document.getElementById(this.arrowID + id);
    console.log('arrowID = ' + this.arrowID + id);

    if (this.isShow === true) {
      icon.style.transition = 'all 0.25s linear';
      icon.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';

    } else {
      icon.style.transition = 'all 0.25s linear';
      icon.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
    }
  }

  /**
   * return state of accordion, if accordion is open then it return true
   * @param event get status of accordion
   */
  isOpen(event) {
    this.openById[event.panelId] = event.nextState;
    this.isShow = this.openById[event.panelId];
  }

}
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating the DOM directly? those changes can be done assigning just a diffrent class with `ngClass`. Also, you clould even use the `animations` property for the `@Component` decorator.

Comment: I'm a beginner on Angular, could you explain to me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

> According to your comment: I'm a beginner on Angular, could you
>   explain to me how to implement this?

I've made a simple example that use basic CSS animation to get its job done.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xedgma?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Sice I've no idea what kind of data are you using I made a simple list of text with a custom property that will handle the `state` :

```
list = [
    {
    name: "test name 1",
    active: false,
    },
    {
    name: "test name 2",
    active: false,
    },
    {
    name: "test name 3",
    active: false,
    },
    {
    name: "test name 4",
    active: false,
    },
  ];
```

The iteration via html is just an `ngFor` with an `ngClass` for each row:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of list; let i = index">
  <div class="single-item" [ngClass]="[data.active ? 'single-item-active':'single-item-not-active']" (click)="toggleActiveClass(i)">
    {{data.name}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

> I've used an ng-container instead of a div because ng-container
>   doesn't get rendered in the DOM.

The css part:

```
.single-item {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.single-item::after {
  content: ' >>> click me';
  cursor: pointer;
}

.single-item-not-active {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.single-item-active {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

finally, the funcion that change state, that need the index of the row iterated:

```
public toggleActiveClass(index: number): void {
    this.list[index].active = !this.list[index].active;
  }
```

**Keep in mind one thing:**

You can't animate every properties in css. For example you can't animate the change of `text-decoration`.

Comment: I approve of your approach method, however it does not work with the <ng-template ngbPanelContent> component...

Comment: You can't apply any DOM manipulation to an ng-template (or ng-container as well) because they doesn't get rendered in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I can't do what I had in mind.